# Как сделать раскрывающийся список в гугл таблицах на основе того, что пустая ячейка или нет

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть ячейка, куда я вбиваю кол-во строк для расчетов. Хочется, чтобы список появлялся рядом с теми ячейками, где ячейка не пустая.

Например

```
Столбец А             Столбец Б
1. Есть значение      Раскрывающийся список
2. Есть значение      Раскрывающийся список
3. Есть значение      Раскрывающийся список
4. Есть значение      Раскрывающийся список
5. Нет значения       Нет списка
```

И, если я стираю, напрмиер в ячейке А4 значение, то и список убирается из ячейки Б2

Comment: P.S. Значения в столбце А ставятся на основе формулы sequence, которая берет кол-во строк из ячейки (условно) В1, поэтому хочется, чтобы проверка данных в столбце Б, выставлялась на основе того, есть ли данные в соседней ячейке столбца А

Comment: Это прям программировать надо. А кто это будет делать? Может быть вам будет проще взять готовое https://t.me/google_sheets/408 ?